# How do you hide specific or certain calendars in the Mavericks Calendars (iCal) App?

Tags: calendar, ical, google-calendar

I have multiple calendars from different services like Gmail, iCloud, etc.  All the calendars together take up too much room to view in the year view of the Calendars app. Also, some calendars are for a specific purpose and I do not want them to display with my "main" calendar listing all the time.  How can I selectively turn on and off individual calendars?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this procedure:

1. Launch the calendars app
2. The default view when first setup hides the calendar listing pane. I am not sure if previous versions hid it by default also.
3. Click View --> Show Calendar List
4. A list of all calendars tied to your accounts will appear. Each calendar name has a checkbox next to it.  Just uncheck the ones that you do not want to display.

[image: Showing/Hiding Calendars]

Also you might see some duplicate entries - for example in holidays.  One way this can occur is if you have a Google Holidays calendar and you also have the Apple Holiday calendar checked - you will see both. Just uncheck one of them to fix this.